# I have a problems with compiler my project UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

When I build code it is fine. But after a run, I have 2 errors:

1. `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`
2. `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! customTableViewCell
       cell.transAmount?.text = "cell number \(indexPath.row)."
       cell.transDate?.text = "cell number \(indexPath.row)."
       return cell
    }
   ```

Debug shows error in:

> let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! customTableViewCell

Comment: In Interface Builder the class of the custom cell is not set to `customTableViewCell`. By the way class names should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: I have found. I made mistake of name idenfirier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you use different identifier or the cell not configured in the storyboard as customTableViewCell